# Is it possible to create a reducer without the createReducer function in ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am going through an existing code and found that there is a reducer created without the use of `createReducer` function syntax.

This `reviewReducer` function from the code snippet below takes the same number of arguments like a reducer and same type of arguments and responds to an action as well (verified after keeping a debugger).

But surprisingly I am not able to find `createReducer` function either in `create-reducer.ts` file or in the entire app. So I want to check if we can create a reducer without it?

create-reducer.ts

```js
import { Action } from 'rxjs/scheduler/Action';

export function reviewReducer(state: State<Any>, action: ReviewActionList{

  return {
    ...state,
    result: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a `reducer` without using the `createReducer()` function. The `createReducer(`) function is a convenience function that can be used to create reducers that follow a particular pattern. However, it is not necessary to use this function.

To create a `reducer` without using `createReducer()`, you can simply define a function that takes two arguments: the current `state` and the `action`. The function should then return the new `state`.

Keep in mind function should be a pure function

Read more about reducers [here](https://this-is-angular.github.io/ngrx-essentials-course/docs/chapter-6/)